# Retrieving Values From A JTextField

Tags: java, swing

I currently building a hotel reservation system, and I'm having issues with retrieving and setting other values from a JTextField.

What I'm trying to do is to retrieve the value that was inputted into a textfield, and then setting that value to a string in another class.

In here, I'm trying to retrieve values from the JTextField:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    GuestInfo gi = new GuestInfo();

    if (event.getSource()==roomView)
    {
        roomViewFrame.setVisible(true);
        roomViewFrame.setSize(1000, 600);

    }

    if (event.getSource()==confirmGuestInfo)
    {
        String firstNameValue = firstNameInput.getText();
        if (firstNameValue.equals("")){
            System.out.printf("Please input first name!");
        }
        else{
            firstNameValue = gi.getFirstName();
        }

        String lastNameValue = lastNameInput.getText();
        if (lastNameValue.equals("")){
            System.out.printf("Please input last name!");
        }
        else{
            lastNameValue = gi.getLastName();
        }

        String addressValue = addressInput.getText();
        if (addressValue.equals("")){
            System.out.printf("Please input address!");
        }
        else{
            addressValue = gi.getAddress();
        }

        String phoneNumberValue = phoneNumberInput.getText();
        if (phoneNumberValue.equals("")){
            System.out.printf("Please input phone number!");
        }
        else{
            phoneNumberValue = gi.getPhoneNumber();
        }
```

This is my GuestInfo ("gi") class:

```
import java.util.*;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.*;
public class GuestInfo {

    public static String firstName;
    public static String lastName;
    public static String address;
    public static String phoneNumber;
    public static String numberOfGuests;
    public static String status; //Still checked in or checked out?
    public static String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public static String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public static String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public String getNumberOfGuests() {
        return numberOfGuests;
    }

    public void setNumberOfGuests(String numberOfGuests) {
        this.numberOfGuests = numberOfGuests;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }





}


/*
 *  JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JButton button = new JButton("YES");

 * public GuestInfo()

{
frame.setLayout(null);
frame.setSize(600, 600);
frame.setVisible(true);
frame.add(button);
button.setBounds(10, 200,300, 300);

}*/
```

Comment: Post your code here not on an external site

Comment: Sorry! Thanks MadProgrammer for fixing it!

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So based on the limited information you've provided, this doesn't make sense...

```
String firstNameValue = firstNameInput.getText();
if (firstNameValue.equals("")){
    System.out.printf("Please input first name!");
}
else{
    firstNameValue = gi.getFirstName();
}
```

Basically, you've asked for the value from the `firstNameInput` field, checked to see if it's blank, but if it's not, you've immediately assigned the value from `gi` to the value `firstNameValue`, which based on the usage of `GuestInfo gi = new GuestInfo();` would render the values blank anyway...

So, you're only accepting values from the UI when they are blank?

This `public static String firstName;` is also a really, really, bad idea.  What happens when you have more then one guest?  They all share the same information?

Comment: Thanks!
For "public static String firstName;", should I create an array of guests instead and store the information that way instead?

Comment: You should first remove the `static` modifiers and you could use a `List` or `Map` of some kind to store them, based on your needs

Answer (score 0):

as MadProgrammer said based on limited info provided, i am assuming that on your *actionPerformed* method you are getting all guest informations to save on guestInfo class. if thats the case, than i guess what you mean is to use the setter methods not the getters as in:

```
String firstNameValue = firstNameInput.getText();
if (firstNameValue.equals("")){
    System.out.printf("Please input first name!");
}
else{
    //firstNameValue = gi.getFirstName(); //not this
    gi.setFirstName(firstNameValue); //but this
}
```

and also all your atributes on guestInfo should be of `private` scope instead of `public` since you are providing the getters for them...